# If $X = X_1+\dotsb+X_N$, and $N\sim\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$, then what is the distribution of $X$ given $N$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I have a question that I'm really struggling with (below): It's hard to understand exactly what is the question actually states. does this mean the number of trials itself is a distribution with a mean of lambda?
Any direction on how to solve would really be appreciated.

> Let $X$ be a random variable defined as the sum of $N$ independent
>   Bernoulli trials in which the probability of each Bernoulli taking the
>   value $1$ is given by $p$. The number of Bernoulli trials $N$ is itself a random
>   variable that behaves according to a Poisson distribution function with
>   the parameter $\lambda$.
>   (a) Derive the conditional distribution function of $X$ given $N = n$ and
>   state your reasoning behind your derivation.
>   (b) Derive the joint distribution function of $X$ and $N$ and state your
>   reasoning behind your derivation.

Comment: Two ways of thinking about it that may help: you draw $N\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, and after seeing its value you draw $N$ independent Bernoulli's and sum them. Another view: you first draw infinitely many Bernoulli's $X_1,\dots, X_n,\dots$, then draw a value of $N\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ at random; and only sum the first $N$ of the infinitely many $X_n$'s. Put differently, $$X = \sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n \mathbb{1}_{\{n \leq N\}}.$$

Comment: $N$ drawn from a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: I still don't know what to do - should I be eliminating a variable?
For part a) Do i treat this as a binomial distribution with n=(lambda/p) number of trials (given that lambda=np for a poisson)?
part b) is it the binomial probability from part a multiplied by the probability distribution for the poisson variable (hence joint distribution)?

Comment: Conditioning on $N=n$, you have a Binomial distribution. (You basically "fix $N=n$ in the above).

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The strange thing is that there is a natural third part of the question, which would be to find the marginal distribution of $X$.  This would have a Poisson distribution with mean $p\lambda$

Comment: Why the edit erasing much of the mathematical content? Is this a preliminary step to a discrete deletion of the question?

Answer (score 3):

We are told that $X = X_1+\dotsb+X_N$, where $N\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$.

a) Essentially, you are asked to compute or give $P(X = k|N = n)$. If I tell you that $N = n$, then the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli trials follows a binomial distribution with $(n,p)$. Hence, $X|N \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$.

b) I believe that you are essentially being asked to compute $P(X = k, N = n) = P(X = k|N = n)P(N = n).$

Comment: It is not a problem. I don't understand. Do you still have a problem or question? Remember, you were "struggling" with this, so maybe it was complex enough. In any case, they might expect you to show some computations (for part a), but I leave it to you.

Comment: Oh, I realized maybe they don't expect you to make  a calculation judging from the way the question is worded. It is well known (you should know) that the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli $p$ trails follows a binomial distribution. Also, I realized you might be confusing this with trying to find the unconditional distribution. I think that's what you are thinking of and those are more "complex". In any case, considering giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck!

Comment: @anon123 It is not a problem; it is the solution. $~$ The joint probability mass function $~p_{X,N}(k, n) ~=~ \Pr(X=k, N=n)~$ *should* be a function of the parameters $p, \lambda$ and the arguments $k, n$.